# Facebook Graph API: get all the friends' likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't particularly fancy the idea of getting a list of friends with 'me/friends' and then iterating over the list to get likes for a particular friend with '%id%/likes' - this takes way to long.

Is there a way to bulk query likes of users' friends in a single API call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use FQL multi-query to get all at once, here is how:

```
{
"friends":"SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())",
"friendsLikes":"SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #friends)",
"pages":"SELECT page_id, name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #friendsLikes)"
}
```

You can test this in http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
You are going to get three result sets one after another, list of friends, list of all of their likes together and then list of page names.
(Note that the query may take a while to execute, so you may want to put a LIMIT on the first line. After **uid1 = me()** put a **LIMIT 5** for example, for testing...)

Then include it in your code in whatever language/platform you are using, for example on iOS:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/

Comment: Great! Now is there a way to group those likes by user id directly in the query?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible. Facebook FQL supports only very basic SQL and there is no JOIN. You can see more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/

Comment: I've tried the same query again and I've got {"error": "Request failed"}. Seems like the resulting json exceeded some threshold size. Also, the inability to group by uid is a real bummer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the same query using the Graph API:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,id,likes.limit(100).fields(id,name)&limit=100

This will solve the issue of the grouping.